# How do I get text between two nodes?

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<class><public>public:<function><type><name>void</name></type>
    there could be text over here but I do not want this.
</function></public></class>
```

How do I get the text from  `<public>`

until `<function>` which is "public:" in this case?

Note this is not necessary followed by function... it could `<sometag>` or `<public/>`

Comment: Please post a minimal, but **complete** example of the XML. -- P.S.  It seems that "public:" is the string value of the `public` element, or at least of its first text node. But it's hard to tell from a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I hinted in the comment to your question, the path to the string `"public:"` in your example is:

`/class/public/text()[1]`

In XSLT, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/class/public/text()[1]" />
```

will return the selected string. If the `public` element does not have any other child text nodes (as is true in your example), you can shorten it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/class/public/text()" />
```

Comment: will it give just public; and the other text?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?